# How to correctly mock an ObjectMapper object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm having a hard time mocking a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

In particular this the class I want to test:

```
@Service
public class ClassToBeTested {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ClassToBeTested(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public void publicMethod(messageDto dto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        try{
            privateMethod(dto, param, "other string");
        } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
           // do stuff
        }
    }


    private void privateMethod(Object dto, String param, String param2) {
        
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

        attributes.putAll(mapper.readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(dto),
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    }));

        attributes.put("level", "error");
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestContextConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class ClassToBeTestedTest {

    @MockBean
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    private ClassToBeTested classToBeTestedActor;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initMock() throws JsonProcessingException {
        when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any())).thenReturn(any());
        when(mapper.readValue(anyString(), Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, 
            Object>>>any())).thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        classToBeTestedActor = new ClassToBeTested(mapper);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFailJsonParsing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Given
        final Dto dto = mock(Dto.class);

        // When
        when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any()))
                .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);

        // Then
        Assertions.assertThrows(JsonProcessingException.class,
                () -> classToBeTestedActor.publicMethod(dto));
    }
}
```

The purpose is to trigger and test the `JsonProcessingException`. The test fails because of an `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 3 recorded:
-> at com.ocado.crm.service.ClassToBeTestedTest.initMock(ClassToBeTestedTest.java:47)
-> at com.ocado.crm.service.ClassToBeTestedTest.initMock(ClassToBeTestedTest.java:48)
-> at com.ocado.crm.service.ClassToBeTestedTest.initMock(ClassToBeTestedTest.java:48)
```

where line 46 and 47 respectively are:

```
when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any())).thenReturn(any());

when(mapper.readValue(anyString(), Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>>any()))
                .thenReturn(new HashMap<>());
```

which makes no sense to me since I think I didn't mixed matchers and raw values.
How can I mock the `ObjectMapper` correctly so that I can test `JsonProcessingException`?

Comment: line 46 -thenReturn method argument doesn't expect Matcher. Try replacing it with, let's say thenReturn("someJSON")

Comment: you were right. that's the problem! Still, no JsonProcessingException is thrown. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The publicMethod is catching the exception. Even if the mock is throwing exception, assert would fail.

Comment: you mean I should catch it in the privateMethod to make the assert success? 'Cause I've tried to catch it in the private method as well with same results

Comment: I forgot to add it while copy-pasting the code. The publicMethod indeed throws JsonProcessingException in the signature. Nevertheless the test fails

Comment: what do you want to test ? If the mapper readValue method is not able to process Json, it will throw JsonProcessingException. That functionality or logic isn't part of your code. So, it's not needed to be tested by you. But, if you have custom logic built like when that exception, do something, then, you should really be testing that do something part.

Comment: I get your point and I kind of agree with that. I just want to understand why, even if I am forcing the mapper to throw that exception, I am unable to assert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the reason behind writing a test which mocks Object Mapper to throw some exception and then test whether the exception was thrown or not. Instead the test should be for the custom logic which is developed by you. If you have a method like this -

```
public void publicMethod(messageDto dto)  {
    try{
        privateMethod(dto, param, "other string");
    } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
       // do stuff
       dto.setXXX("XXX"); // The test should be testing this
    }
}
```

So, the test should be testing whether the dto is set correctly.

```
@Test
public void shouldFailJsonParsing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Given
        final Dto dto = new Dto();

        // When
        when(mapper.writeValueAsString(any()))
                .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);

        // Invoke the method to be tested
        classToBeTestedActor.publicMethod(dto);

        // Test whether expected mock methods are invoked
        verify(mapper, times(1)).writeValueAsString(any());
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mapper);

        // Assert results
        Assert.assertEquals("XXX", dto.getXXX());
    }
```

> I get your point and I kind of agree with that. I just want to
> understand why, even if I am forcing the mapper to throw that
> exception, I am unable to assert it

I think the reason for this is that the exception is catched by you. That is the reason, that exception isn't propagated to your test.

```
public void publicMethod(messageDto dto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        try{
            privateMethod(dto, param, "other string");
        } catch(JsonProcessingException e){
           // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Try changing this to -

```
public void publicMethod(messageDto dto) throws JsonProcessingException {
        privateMethod(dto, param, "other string");
        
    }
```